# How to pass data to JavaScript ajax xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, web, post

```
function fetchJSONFile(isRest, path, callback) {
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        if (callback) callback(data);
      }
    }
  };

  httpRequest.open('POST', path, true);
  if (isRest) {
    let mail = "***";
    let pw = "***";
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + window.btoa(mail + ":" + pw));
  }
  httpRequest.send("--data '[1, 2]'"); // also tried data=[1, 2]
}
```

I want to pass my data to the request, so that i'm able to get a response with the data i need. Currently i'm getting 415 error. What's wrong with my code?

Curl for api:

```
curl --user test@gmail.com:secret -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    http://localhost:8888/api/quizzes/1/solve --data '[1, 2]'
```

Comment: What format of payload is the API expecting?

Comment: Why isn't the data a parameter to the function?

Comment: @Barmar that's how you do it with curl:"curl --user test@gmail.com:secret -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
http://localhost:8888/api/quizzes/1/solve --data '[1, 2]'" and i have not made a data parameter cuz i've yet just used static data

Comment: `--data` is a `curl` option, it's not actually part of the data that gets sent to the server.

Comment: `httpRequest.send('[1, 2]')`

Comment: @Barmar now i'm getting CORS Missing Allow Origin Errors, after adding
`httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");`
`httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`
i still get them...

Answer (score 0):

According the curl, you need to also set as header the `Content-Type`,
it would look something like this:

```js
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

and then send with JSON.stringify method to make sure you send JSON in proper string format.

```js
httpRequest.send(JSON.stringify({ myKey: 'myValue' });
```

Comment: thanks added your suggestion to my code, the problem i got now now is that i'm getting CORS Missing Allow Origin Errors, after adding `httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");` `httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`
i still get them, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: CORS issue normally is not frontend side, it is backend side that doesn’t accepting the request outside their domain, hence I believe the issue is not in our context anymore.

Comment: So it's out of my area to change anything if i can't make changes to the backend?

Comment: Like, imagine, if we're on localhost, and you try to communicate to production server, some backend doesn't allow communication with external party, like in this case it's us.. so you need to ask the backend developer about the issue.